# How to install py3-ready?

Tags: ros, python3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I am following the following [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/UsingPython3/IdentifyDependencies) to migrate a package from python2 to python3.

I need to install the py3-ready tool, and it is said that the installation guide is in de README of its [github](https://github.com/osrf/py3-ready) but there is no installation guide.

Anybody can help me to install it?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361123/how-to-install-py3-ready?/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2020-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are now install instructions for `py3-ready` here: https://github.com/osrf/py3-ready#install

In short: install Debian package dependencies matching the default version of `python` on your system.

Python 2 (Ubuntu Bionic, Debian Stretch, etc)

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-apt python-rosdep-modules python-catkin-pkg-modules
$ pip install py3-ready
```

Python 3 (Ubuntu Focal, Debian Buster, etc)

```
$ sudo apt-get install python3-apt python3-rosdep-modules python3-catkin-pkg-modules
$ pip install py3-ready
```

---

Originally posted by [sloretz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23470/sloretz/) with karma: 3061 on 2020-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0